# What handles requests made to a WebMethod in asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, exception, webmethod

I'm trying to implement generic error handling.

```cs
public partial class SomePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
//...
    [WebMethod()]
    public static int SomeMethod()
    {
        //... some code
        //... exception
    }
//...
}
```

Regular requests could be processed with global.asax, but static WebMethods are not going through Application_BeginRequest or Application_Error. I tried writing an attribute, deriving from ExceptionFilterAttribute and using OnException override, but it didn't work either.

So who handles those requests?

Client call is made through jQuery ajax request below:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SomePage.aspx/SomeMethod",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (response) {
        someVar = response.d;
    },
    error: function (a, b, c) {
        console.log(a); 
        // handle 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation it looks like you need to build a SOAP Extension to handle the errors globally - useful snippet and link below:

> A Web application can be comprised of multiple Web services. However,
>   the Application_Error event within the Global.asax Syntax file cannot
>   be used for global exception handling. The HttpHandler for Web
>   services consumes any exception that occurs while a Web service is
>   executing and turns it into a SOAP fault before the Application_Error
>   event is called. Build a SOAP extension to process Web service
>   exceptions in a global exception handler. A SOAP extension can check
>   for the existence of an exception in the ProcessMessage method. Within
>   the ProcessMessage method, check the Exception property of the
>   SoapMessage passed when the Stage property is set to AfterSerialize.
>   For details on SOAP extensions, see SOAP Message Modification Using
>   SOAP Extensions.

Excerpt from [Handling and Throwing Exceptions in XML Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds492xtk.aspx) (I believe there are examples to help you along the way too)

Additionally Rick Strahl (MVP) wrote this on the topic a while ago which fixes the problem in situ but doesn't address your need for managing the problem globally http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2005/Jan/29/NET-Web-Services-and-unhandled-Exceptions

This post should guide you toward building a soap extension for global error handling as per your requirements http://geekswithblogs.net/pavelka/archive/2005/09/05/HowToCreateAGlobalExceptionHandlerForAWebService.aspx

Comment: Actually, those posts are talking about SOAP exceptions and in my case it's HTTP GET/POST, so the exception thrown is status code 500, and not SOAP exception/fault. :(
But thanks anyway!

Comment: Interesting - what does the HTTP GET/POST message look like - could you post it? How are you calling the WebMethod?

Comment: I call it from client with JQuery:
'$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SomePage.aspx/SomeMethod",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {
                    someVar = response.d;
                },
                error: function (a, b, c) {
                    console.log(a);
                    // handle
                }
            });'

However, I wish to catch the errors at server side.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info - does the call always fail (i.e. can you make successful requests sometimes?)

Comment: Yes, sure. Most of the time the requests are successful. Requests return serialized JSON data.

Comment: if you hit F12 on the attribute where does it take you do you end up in the meta file for System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute or a different namespace/class - just want to double check?

Comment: Yes, that's a System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute :)